# What is the best way to convert text to outlines?

Tags: fonts, print-design, pdf, export

I know convertthis is horrible and I cringe every time the printer asks.

However, my team builds our files in InDesign and supplies print PDFs. The printer opens the PDFs in Illustrator or a program similar. (They are based in Asia. I assume this is common practice, since it happens a lot...) They **always** request for us to convert our PDFs to outlines. I know this is bad practice and I cringe every time the printer asks, but I do not have the luxury of going to a different printer.

In the past, I have created a flattener preset in InDesign, but it leaves white line artefacts around the images. Even if I tell the printer those lines will not print, they still want us to save a different way.
So is there a better way?

1. Convert to outlines in InDesign when exporting to PDF with a flattener preset – which leaves lines?
2. Convert text to outlines by using flattener preview in Adobe Acrobat?

I would prefer a solution that does not require my team to export a PDF, then open in another program, then open in Illustrator to verify.

Comment: I kind of think the "better way" is to not have to outline text.. so a different print provider perhaps. I think Acrobat's flattener with the option to convert to outlines works well.

Comment: @Scott. Haha. I agree. Unfortunately, most of our Asian suppliers are requesting this. I do not have the luxury of going to a different printer. :/